# Eclipse PHP would sometime enter tabs on arrays despite settings

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, eclipse-pdt

So for eclipse PHP I set the tab policy to spaces with indentation size 3 from window->preferences->PHP-> Code Style -> Formatter

normally it enters 3 spaces instead of tab normally

but sometimes when I'm inside an array

```
$php = array(

);
```

and then I press tab, it would instead enter a tab character...

Is there a way to resolve this so that it always displays 3 spaces?

Comment: I use vi now, but I observed the same bug as you (I think) when I was using eclipse. I think it occurs when the first thing on the line is a string (which a key in your array might be)